# Checking if a value appears again by group

Tags: r, duplicates, unique

**I am working in R**

**sample data:**

I have people which have an id which has been assigned from their social security/national insurance number (actual_id). actual_id is assumed to be correct.

This column may not be needed, but I have worked out how many times each person appears in the data (number). e.g. we can see the person with actual_id = 1 appears twice in the data, so number = 2 for this person.

I have created a new method of id-ing people, which has nothing to do with social security/national insurance number. The new method has generated an id which is in the proposed_id column.

```
df <- data.frame(actual_id = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3), 
                 proposed_id = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "d", "b"), 
                 number = c(2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2))

print(df)
```

| actual_id | number | proposed_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | a |
| 1 | 2 | a |
| 2 | 3 | b |
| 2 | 3 | b |
| 2 | 3 | c |
| 3 | 2 | d |
| 3 | 2 | b |

**Desired outcome**

I want a way of assessing if the proposed_id is used only once for any actual_id:

- We can see that proposed_id = a has been allocated to actual_id = 1, and does not appear again in proposed_id column. This would therefore be allocated "TRUE".
- We can see that proposed_id = b has been allocated to actual_id = 2, but it has then been allocated further down to proposed_id = 3. This would be allocated as "FALSE".

My actual data has 90,000 rows.

| actual_id | number | proposed_id | assessment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | a | TRUE |
| 1 | 2 | a | TRUE |
| 2 | 3 | b | FALSE |
| 2 | 3 | b | FALSE |
| 2 | 3 | c | TRUE |
| 3 | 2 | d | TRUE |
| 3 | 2 | b | FALSE |

Comment: Please try the sample code you give us, yours fails with `Error: object 'a' not found`  ... _fixed_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## base R

```r
with(df, ave(actual_id, proposed_id, FUN = function(z) length(unique(z)) == 1)) > 0
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

## dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(assessment = n_distinct(actual_id) == 1, .by = proposed_id)
#   actual_id proposed_id number assessment
# 1         1           a      2       TRUE
# 2         1           a      2       TRUE
# 3         2           b      3      FALSE
# 4         2           b      3      FALSE
# 5         2           c      3       TRUE
# 6         3           d      2       TRUE
# 7         3           b      2      FALSE
```

## data.table

```r
library(data.table)
as.data.table(df)[, assessment := uniqueN(actual_id) == 1, by = "proposed_id"][]
#    actual_id proposed_id number assessment
#        <num>      <char>  <num>     <lgcl>
# 1:         1           a      2       TRUE
# 2:         1           a      2       TRUE
# 3:         2           b      3      FALSE
# 4:         2           b      3      FALSE
# 5:         2           c      3       TRUE
# 6:         3           d      2       TRUE
# 7:         3           b      2      FALSE
```

---

Sample data

```r
df <- structure(list(actual_id = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3), proposed_id = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "d", "b"), number = c(2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Comment: Thanks to those who have responded. Super helpful and clear! :)
Has worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

You can try

```
transform(
    df,
    assessment = ave(actual_id, proposed_id)==actual_id
)
```

or

```
transform(
    df,
    assessment = !ave(actual_id, proposed_id, FUN = \(x) diff(range(x)))
)
```

which gives

```
  actual_id proposed_id number assessment
1         1           a      2       TRUE
2         1           a      2       TRUE
3         2           b      3      FALSE
4         2           b      3      FALSE
5         2           c      3       TRUE
6         3           d      2       TRUE
7         3           b      2      FALSE
```

Comment: Nice, I hadn't thought to use `FUN=mean`. However ... both of these assume  that  `actual_id` is numeric, perhaps not always a safe assumption with an "ID" field.

Comment: @r2evans yes, it presumes numeric in the `actual_id` column. and your version is more generalized to other data types.